# What is the difference between new <childclass>() and new <parentclass>()?

Tags: java, class, instance, extends

I'm a java newbie, so please help me understand this.

e.g

```
class a{...}
class b extends a{
   public static void main(...){
      a x = new a();
      b y = new b();
      a z = new b();
    }
```

What is the difference between the three instances? When should I use each one?

edit: corrected the last statement

Comment: 3rd statement will not compile.

Comment: you can create an instance for b and assign it to a... a x = new b();

Comment: @Juvanis: 3rd statement will compile.

Comment: @Aniket the post is edited, see previous versions.

Comment: @Juvanis: Ohh! Sorry. I had not noticed.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `a` as a parameter to a method for **code reuse**..i.e we could define a method(with parameter `a`) so general that it work with any of its deriving class(`b`,..)

---

For example:Consider this method to read a Stream

```
public void Read(Stream s)
{
   //read s
}
```

Now you can reuse this method with all of the `deriving` classes of `Stream`

```
Read(new FileStream(PATH));//read File
Read(new NetworkStream(URL));//read url
Read(new MemoryStream(object));//read memory object
```

Answer (score 1):

This won't compile

```
b z = new a();
```

What you probably meant here is

```
a z = new b();
```

i.e. assigning a child class object to a parent class reference to make use of *polymorphism*.

Basically, if you have a sub-type object assigned to a super-class reference the *runtime polymorphism* makes sure that the sub-type's version of an *instance method* gets called i.e. if it has been defined in the parent class as well and you wish to *override* it of course. If not, the call falls back upon the super-class version transparently.

As a side note, please make use of `CapitalCamelCase` for classes.

Answer (score 1):

`a z=new b();` this is runtime polymorphism

```
class a{...}
class b extends a{
   public static void main(...){
      a x = new a();
      b y = new b();
      a z = new b();
    }
```

`a x=new a();` -> this is the object of the parent class.

`b y =new b();` y is the object of the child class.

`a z=new b();` z it is the object of the parent class refering the child instance

suppose if you have some functions(hello()) inside the parent class and the child class override the functions(hello()) then your z objects use  that functions(); only in the child class,other functions inside the child cannot be available to that object(z).

click  the [link](http://www.javatpoint.com/runtime-polymorphism-in-java) for more info

Comment: Please explain the answer, only link is not sufficient because in future if link is not valid then you answer would be of no use.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, if the extended class has two more new functions, then z will not have access to those two functions, because although it is referring to the extended class, it is still an object of the parent class, where those functions are not available. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

First of all please follow java conventions. Class name start with caps and method/variable names are in camle case.

```
class A{...}
class B extends A{
   public static void main(...){
      A x = new A();
      B y = new B();
      B z = new A(); // will not work
    }
```

Statement 1 & 2 : `A x = new A();` & `B y = new B();`
This is normal way of creating objects. You have a reference of type A pointing to object of type A(same class). Same goes for the 2nd one.

statement 3: `B z = new A();`
This will not work as you cannot use reference of subclass type to point to object of superclass simply because your subclass reference can have methods not defined in your superclass object.

You may want to try `A z = new B();` - It is called Polymorphism. Google the term for more information. Lot of tuts out there.